# $\mathcal O=\tilde{\mathcal O}$ iff $\quad \lim\ d(x_n,x)=0\Leftrightarrow\lim\tilde{d}(x_n,x)=0$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathcal O$, $\tilde{\mathcal O}$ be 2 topologies, induced on $X$ by $d,\tilde d$(metrics) respectively.any sequence. Show that;
>
> $\mathcal O=\tilde{\mathcal O}\quad$ iff $\quad$ For any sequence $(x_n)_n\subset X,$ the limit$\quad\lim\ d(x_n,x)=0\Leftrightarrow\lim\tilde{d}(x_n,x)=0$.

$\Rightarrow$ by contradiction

If $\lim\ d(x_n,x)=0$ but $\lim\tilde{d}(x_n,x)≠0$ for some $x$, then $(x_n)_n\cup\{x\}$ is closed in $\mathcal O$ and the complement is open, but not in $\tilde{\mathcal O}.$

Can you give me a hint for the other direction?

Comment: @ChristophPegel Yes, i write it in short form, to be clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a set $A$ which is in ${\mathcal O} \setminus \tilde {\mathcal O}$ and let $C$ be the complementary set of $A$. Then $C$ is $d$-closed but not $\tilde d$- closed. Hence there is a sequence $x_n\in C$ and a point $x\in C$ such that $x_n\to x$ with respect to $d$ but not with respect to $\tilde d$. This contradicts you hypothesys. Hence $\mathcal O \subset \tilde {\mathcal O}$. By symmetry also the reverse inclusion holds.

Comment: but this doesn't contradict the condition on the RHS. x can also be a limit point of C w.r.t. $\tilde{d}$ without being in C